# How can I span one column over 2 rows?

Tags: html, html-table

I have my code:

```
       <table>
            <caption>Average salary</caption>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Occupation</th>
                <th colspan="2">Salary (kr)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <th>Men</th>
                <th>Women</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Assistant nurse</th>
                <td>24 500</td>
                <td>24 800</td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Consultant system development</th>
                <td>43 000</td>
                <td>43 500</td>

            </tr>


        </table>
```

and it looks like this

[image]

how can I make the "occupation" heading span the two first rows also? Just adding `rowspan` after `colspan` does not work.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_th_rowspan_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  *can*  add `rowspan="2"` to the first cell, but then you have to omit the first cell in the second row:

```css
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
            <caption>Average salary</caption>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Occupation</th>
                <th colspan="2">Salary (kr)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Men</th>
                <th>Women</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Assistant nurse</th>
                <td>24 500</td>
                <td>24 800</td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Consultant system development</th>
                <td>43 000</td>
                <td>43 500</td>

            </tr>


        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it this : `<th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Occupation</th>`

You have to put rowspan also to expand to two rows.